# Buzzy noise on headphones from laptop

Tags: laptop, headphones, noise

Audible buzzy noise in headphones (Audio-Technica ATH-M20X Professional Studio Monitor Headphones, Black) plugged in by wire into a (Dell Latitude E5470 laptop.

Noise volume lessens if my hands are laying flat on the laptop, and rises if my hands are removed off the laptop.

Noise is constant while charging and not charging. Any suggestions?

---

I will close this after receiving everyone's help. It seems to be feedback from a nearby monitor. Thank you!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Does it occur when Charging or when Disconnected ? Does it occur when connecting Desktop Speakers too or only with Head Phones ? New laptop within Warranty Period should be exchanged or repaired !

Comment: Please edit your question to add actual details on your laptop and headphones. What is the make and model of each. How are your headphones connected to the laptop? Wire or Bluetooth or something else? Might also help if you could add details on what OS this laptop uses and if this is something that just suddenly happened or has been a persistent issue. As it stands, without real details this question will be closed. Not out of a lack of desire to help, but no details means any “answer” will just be grasping at straws.

Comment: Noise even without Charging means It is a Serious Electrical Issue : It should be repaired before something bad happens ! ( Eg Battery Exploding or CPU / Mother Board / Capacitor getting Damaged )

Comment: By "not charging:" have you completely disconnected it from **all** devices plugged into the mains, e.g., external monitor, USB hard drive with its own power supply, etc. If the buzz disappears, it's a grounding issue. Try connecting metal on the case or chassis to an earth ground, such as the ground connection or screw on an outlet.